# Conditional Probability Question..

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If one check in 10,000 is forged, 5% of all checks are postdated, and 60% of forged checks are postdated, find the probability that a postdated check is forged.

Comment: Do you know Bayes' rule? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem

Comment: How can I use that in this situation?

Comment: Also, welcome to stack exchange. I recommend taking the time to actually struggle with the concepts and the formula I gave you. You took three minutes -- that's not enough time to embrace the feeling of confusion you have to feel in order to get an 'aha' moment.

Finally, please take the time to accept correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the event that the check is forged and $B$ denote the event that the check is post-dated. You want the probability of a check being forged given that it is post-dated, i.e. $P(A | B)$. By Bayes' rule,
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)}.$$
$P(A)$ is the probability that the check is forged. $P(B)$ is the probability that a check is post-dated. $P(B|A)$ is the probability that check is post-dated given that it is forged. You have all these numbers; plug and play.